# Why is JQuery messing with the params I want to bind to a click handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In short, I'm doing this:

```
function myHandler(a,b,c,d){
    doStuffWithMyParams(a,b,c,d);
}
```

Then somewhere else:

```
jqueryElem.click(myHandler.bind(a,b,c,d));
```

When I do, some of the parameters passed (a,b) are read correctly. But the third (c) is a JQuery event object. I've also tried binding the args as an array. Then, the first param becomes the event object.

Totally perplexed here. Thanks in advance for any direction on this.

Comment: and what try pass object instead of array

Comment: @daremachine I can try that -- why do you suggest it?

Comment: Is there a chance that your parameter name is the same as a name used in jQuery?

Comment: jquery doc says .bind( eventType [, eventData ], handler ) .. so if event data will be json object or object, array it can pass normaly, but in one parameter

Comment: What are the types of a,b,c and d respectively?

Comment: @daremachine okay -- will give it a try.

Comment: @ArcaneCraeda all strings

Comment: @jasonwarford (week, weekday, idxShift, positionId) -- any of those reserved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on what epascarello wrote, this should do the trick:

```
jqueryElem.click(myHandler.bind(this,[a,b,c,d]));
```

Not having the array might cause `b` to be treated as an `eventHandler`. Notice I used an array, but it could also be an object, for instance.

Comment: Yes, exactly right. Now that I think about it, this makes a lot of sense. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: exacly what doc says :) but pass 'this' to eventType do the trick. Nice btw.

Answer (score 2):

With the code `myHandler.bind(a,b,c,d)`, the argument `a` is the context that bind() uses

So my handler is actually seeing this

```
function myHandler(b,c,d,event){
```

So I have a feeling you want

```
jqueryElem.click(myHandler.bind(this, a,b,c,d));
```

Comment: That makes sense -- 'this' is an event object in jquery callbacks after all. Let me give that a go.

Comment: @ArcaneCraeda's answer took it the distance for me. I believe your solution would work if I needed to be passing fewer parameters. Thanks for pushing this in the right direction though.